# issue with for loops in 2D array program

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Okay so my current assignment has me making a program that can mimic percolation, meaning that it has to read an array, where 1 means the space is closed, 0 means the space is open. Next, it must change all the 0's at the top row of the array to 2's representing the liquid being poured in. The liquid can then follow the 0's (representing the flow), changing them all to twos along the way. Liquid can move up, down, left, and right. not diagonal. I have my program almost working, but the for loops don't seem to go through more than the first row of the array.

```
public class Percolation2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[][] filter1 = {{1,0,1,0,1,1,0}, 
                {1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
                {0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
                {1,1,0,1,1,1,1}, 
                {1,0,0,1,1,0,1},
                {1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                {0,0,0,0,1,1,0}, 
                {1,1,1,0,1,0,1}};
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            if(filter1[0][i] ==0) {
                filter1[0][i] = 2;
            }
        }

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < filter1.length ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < filter1[i].length ; j++ ) {

                if ( filter1[i][j] == 0 )

                    if(i-1 > 0 && filter1[i-1][j] == 2)
                        filter1[i][j] = 2;

                    if(i+1 < 7 && filter1[i+1][j] ==2)
                        filter1[i][j] = 2;

                    if(j-1 > 0 && filter1[i][j-1]==2)
                        filter1[i][j] = 2;

                    if(j+1 < 7 && filter1[i][j+1] == 2)
                        filter1[i][j] = 2;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < filter1.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < filter1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(filter1[i][j]);
                if(j < filter1[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } 
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

So you can clearly tell that it is not looping properly.

Comment: I suggest you format your code with proper indentation.  That will make it easier to read.  Also have you tried to use a debugger to observe step-by-step execution of your program?

Comment: It looks to me you are (at least) missing a curly bracket around the code after `if(filter1[i][j] == 0)` in the double `for` loop. And shouldnt your first row be `1 2 1 2 1 1 2`  ... not all `2`s?

Comment: `if(filter1[i][j] == 0)` in the second loop. The first row does not contain any 0's why this guard is skipped.

Comment: Well, he did the first row "manually", the double `for` loop will effectively skip the first row (no `0`s), but should continue on for the others, when `i > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Each turn the liquid can move one level.  Your for statements are correct, all elements of the array are visited.  You need another loop for the proper amount of turns.

I don't want to give you the answer directly as there is a lesson to be learned here, you need to have something like:

```
//Init
boolean done = false;

while(!done) {

   for (int i = 0; i < filter1.length; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < filter1[i].length; j++) {
        if(filter1[i][j] == 0)
        ....
     }
   }

   //add the print matrix code here if you want it done after each turn.

   done = amIDone();
}
```

Overall your code is structured pretty poorly.  You should make use of constants for the array lengths, and you could also define methods for your two doubly nested for loops.  At the bare mininum, I would have a `printMatrix()` method.

Comment: The above is not complete code. As he said, he wasn't going to give you the direct answer.

Comment: I can't seem to get code to enter into the comments, but ill just keep working at it. thanks anyway guys

Comment: To add code into a comment here, surround the code with the backquote. Thats the button to the left of `1` ... with the ~ on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems here:

1) You seemed to have left out curly brackets around the block of code following  `if(filter1[i][j] == 0)` in your double `for` loop.

2) Below that, your check for out-of-bounds is incorrect  `if(i-1 > 0 && ...` should be  `if(i-1 >= 0 && ...`. And, `if(j+1 < 7 && ...`  should be `if(j+1 < 8 && ...`

3) In your question you say that your output is `2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...` . But your code produces different results, your output should be `1 2 1 2 1 1 2 ...`. Thats what I get when I run `for(int i=0; i<7; i++) { if(filter1[0][i] == 0) { filter1[0][i] = 2; } }`

4) Pete hints at the problem. But more specifically, you are doing one pass down the matrix (2D array). There is no ability to go up with the liquid (nor left).

Lets call these items cells. And when a cell gets liquid (a.k.a. it turns to == `2`), it should percolate that liquid to the neighboring cells which are empty (a.k.a. set to `0`). This sounds like a call for recursion, IMHO!

Once you fix the first three issues. Put the payload of your double `for` loop into a recursive function such as this here:

```
public void percolate(int x, int y) {
    if ( filter1[x][y] == 0 ) {
        if(x-1 >= 0 && filter1[x-1][y] == 2) filter1[x][y] = 2;
        if(x+1 < 7 && filter1[x+1][y] == 2) filter1[x][y] = 2;
        if(y-1 >= 0 && filter1[x][y-1] == 2) filter1[x][y] = 2;
        if(y+1 < 8 && filter1[x][y+1] == 2) filter1[x][y] = 2;
        if ( filter1[x][y] == 2 ) {
            if ( x-1 >= 0 ) percolate(x-1,y);
            if ( x+1 < 7 ) percolate(x+1,y);
            if ( y-1 >= 0 ) percolate(x,y-1);
            if ( y+1 < 8 ) percolate(x,y+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call it for each cell in your double `for` loop. Actually, since the liquid starts at the top, I guess you could just call this `percolate` for each cell in the *second* row, only. It will percolate down and round from there.

As you might can see, this is not the most efficient solution, it double/triple checks for percolation on some cells. But this is the slim, nuts and bolts version.

EDIT: Fixed typeos, got rid of unnecessary boolean.